# Lodash: remove duplicates by comparing id and other properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have problems to search for methods from Lodash and have tried both `uniqBy` and `uniqWith` but didn't work as it always returns the first occurrence if there are similarities in `id`. Not sure if for loop options are good enough because of the huge volumes of data in reality.

This is a simple version:

```
var currentUserId = 1
var routes = [
    { id: 1, status: 0, memberId: 3},
    { id: 2, status: 1, memberId: 2},
    { id: 3, status: 1, memberId: null},
    { id: 2, status: 0, memberId: 1},
    { id: 4, status: 0, memberId: 1},
    { id: 5, status: 1, memberId: 2},
    { id: 5, status: 1, memberId: 1},
]
```

The result should prioritize unique id. At the same time, it checks if more than 1 occurrences happen the same `id` and different `memberId`. In this case, it should pick the object with `memberId === currentUserId`.

So it should be like this:

```
var result = [
    { id: 1, status: 0, memberId: 3},
    { id: 2, status: 0, memberId: 1},
    { id: 3, status: 1, memberId: null},
    { id: 4, status: 0, memberId: 1},
    { id: 5, status: 1, memberId: 1},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution is to sort the array first and then filter out the unique ids.

### **Vanilla JS**

1. Use [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to prevent the mutation of the original array when we sort it.
2. Sort the array by `id` and `memberId` respectively by using [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
3. Use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to only retain routes where the preceding route doesn't have the same `id` as the current one.

---

```
var result = routes
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id || a.memberId - b.memberId)
    .filter((r, i, a) => !i || r.id - a[i-1].id);
```

```js
const currentUserId = 1;
const routes = [
    { id: 1, status: 0, memberId: 3},
    { id: 2, status: 1, memberId: 2},
    { id: 3, status: 1, memberId: null},
    { id: 2, status: 0, memberId: 1},
    { id: 4, status: 0, memberId: 1},
    { id: 5, status: 1, memberId: 2},
    { id: 5, status: 1, memberId: 1},
];

var result = routes
 .slice()
 .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id || a.memberId - b.memberId)
 .filter((r, i, a) => !i || r.id - a[i-1].id);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0!important;}
```

### Lodash

1. Use [lodash#sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy) to sort `id` and `memberId` respectively.
2. Use [lodash#uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) to get the unique routes by `id`.
3. Use [lodash#value](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#value) to get the final result.

> If you're wondering how chaining works in lodash, you can visit the [implicit chaining](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash) and [explicit chaining](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chain) links.

---

```
const result = _(routes)
  .sortBy(['id', 'memberId'])
  .uniqBy('id')
  .value();
```

```js
const currentUserId = 1;
const routes = [
    { id: 1, status: 0, memberId: 3},
    { id: 2, status: 1, memberId: 2},
    { id: 3, status: 1, memberId: null},
    { id: 2, status: 0, memberId: 1},
    { id: 4, status: 0, memberId: 1},
    { id: 5, status: 1, memberId: 2},
    { id: 5, status: 1, memberId: 1},
];

const result = _(routes)
  .sortBy(['id', 'memberId'])
  .uniqBy('id')
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for loadash just use a filter

```js
var currentUserId = 1
var routes = [
    { id: 1, status: 0, memberId: 3},
    { id: 2, status: 1, memberId: 2},
    { id: 3, status: 1, memberId: null},
    { id: 2, status: 0, memberId: 1},
    { id: 4, status: 0, memberId: 1},
    { id: 5, status: 1, memberId: 2},
    { id: 5, status: 1, memberId: 1},
];

const unique = (routes, userId) => routes.filter(
  (route, index) => !routes.some(
    (r, i) => r.id === route.id && index !== i && route.memberId !== userId
  )
);

console.log(unique(routes, currentUserId));
```

and if you want to order by id add a .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)